# Derived certificate from private key in iOS(Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, elliptic-curve

I am able to generate ECC key pair on iOS (Objective-C).
Now I want to derive certificate from the generated private key?
In android normally we do:

- initialize KeyStore, KeyPairGenerator
- generate key pair with identifier (later retrieve with the identifier)
- retrieve entry from keystore by identifier `KeyStore.Entry entry = ks.getEntry(identifier, null);`
- get private key by calling `((KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) entry).getPrivateKey()`
- get certificate by calling `ks.getCertificate(identifier)`
- derived public key from certificate by calling `ks.getCertificate(keyHandle).getPublicKey()`

How can I export certificate in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I found some link regarding **ECC** encryption in iOS hope this will helps you to head into it.

- [Github link for ECC encryption](https://github.com/ricmoo/GMEllipticCurveCrypto)
- **Some SO links** 
  [How to use ECC in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563229/how-to-use-ecc-in-ios)

  [Elliptic Curve Crypto in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916695/elliptic-curve-crypto-in-ios)

  http://pastebin.com/3JBbzpX6

**Extra Link for ECC**

https://digitalleaves.com/blog/2015/10/sharing-public-keys-between-ios-and-the-rest-of-the-world/

Hope this will helps you.

Happy coding.